# Command line ends up at a blank prompt after execvp()

Tags: c, shell

Pretty much everything works like it's supposed to, except when it gets to if(execvp.....). The if statement will work fine, but it will not return to the command line. If /bin/ls, it will print everything, but the very next line will be blank besides the cursor. Same if it reaches printf(..."Command not found"...). My best guess is that the parent process finishes/terminates before the child, but I haven't found a remedy if that's the problem. Hopefully the problem lies in eval.
(This isn't a copy/paste so there might be small errors)

```
void eval(char *cmdline)
{
    int bg;
    char *argv[MAXARGS];
    pid_t pid;
    sigset_t mask;
    ///
    bg = parseline(cmdline, argv);
    ///
    if (!builtin_cmd(argv)) {
        sigemptyset(&mask);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGSTP);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
        ///
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            unix_error("...");
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
            setpgid(0,0);
            ///
            if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) {
                printf("Command not found");
                exit(0);
            }
         }
        else { //state of process: FG == foreground, BG== background
             if (!bg) {
                 addjob(jobs, pid, FG, comdline);
                 sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
                 waitfg(pid); //waits for pid to not be foreground process
             }
             else { 
                   // same as above, except swap FG for BG and no waitfg()
             }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to happen. `execvp` will only return on error, returning `-1` which will test **true**, otherwise, there is no return from it. (which is also why `_exit` rather than `exit` is recommended in that case -- to eliminate the corner-case where an `atexit` function is set in the parent -- that will then fail following a failed `execvp` -- the `_exit` function suppresses execution of any such functions.)

Comment: @David I expect it to exit then let the parent process continue so I can type in the command line again. Instead, the child will print like expected, but then the very next line in the terminal will be completely blank. Typing and/or hitting enter will just move it to another blank line. My only option from there is to exit/restart the terminal. Hopefully, that clear things up.

Comment: No. When you call `execvp` it is the same as calling `exec` in your shell. The `execvp` process takes the place of the current process -- period. When the command called be `execvp` terminates - the entire process terminates. That is why you are calling it in a forked child process to begin with (instead of just calling it in a loop). The only time the parent will ever be involved again is if the call to `execvp` fails, then `-1` is returned -- otherwise -- there is no return of any kind. (you can think of `execvp` as a *fire-and-forget* missile. You send it on its way -- it does the rest.)